# Get the selected option from f.select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Sorry if this is a repeated question but I have been looking for the solution with no luck.
I want to know how can I use the selected option (or where is it stored) from a form like that:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@something) do |f| %>    

     <%= f.select :example, @example.map {|example1| [example.atributte1, example.attribute2]} %>

<% end %>
```

I need to pass the option to a partial. I use Rails 3.0.1

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the form is submitted the selected option appears in the params hash as any other form input.
Assuming @something is a Something model instance:

```
params[:something][:example]
```

Should supply you with the selected value.